# event.stopPropagation() in Angular app leads to jasmine timing out

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, angular6

In my Angular app, I have two clickable divs, where one is the child of the other. When the child div is clicked, I don't want the parent click event to be triggered, so I use stopPropagation() on the click event. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
<div id="parent" (click)="parentClick($event)">
  Parent
  <div id="child" (click)="childClick($event)">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `childClick`'s first line is `event.stopPropagation();`

No problem here, everything works as intended. You can check out [the code and demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vzlvz)

---

However, when I'm trying to do a jasmine test that clicks the child div, jasmine timeouts. It seems like jasmine freezes for some reason. The unit test looks like this:

```
it(`Clicking child doesn't trigger parent`, () => {
        let childDe = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#child'));
        childDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.lastClicked).toBe('child');
    });
```

When I run it, jasmine loads for a very long time and outputs this message:
`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

If anybody knows how to create a jasmine unit test in stackblitz, let me know and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not fully satisfied with this, I made it work by using the nativeElement instead of the debugElement and running the click function on that, as follows:

```
it(`Clicking child doesn't trigger parent`, () => {
        let childEl = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#child');
        childEl.click();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.lastClicked).toBe('child');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I just want to make sure that the error and the cause that you are presenting are related. The error `Async callback was not invoked...` is usually given when you have a `done` argument to the function provided to `it`:

```
it('some test', (done) => { 
    ...
    done();
});
```

The error occurs when `done` is not called after some amount of time. However, if you do not have a `done` argument, the test operates synchronously and cannot asynchronously timeout.

Because the code you provided does not contain the `done` argument, I am thinking this error might be caused in a test other than this one and has nothing to do with event propagation.

However, if you are using something like `Protractor` things could get a little more complicated, but that wasn't mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer! Indeed, I do not have a done argument provided to it. Jasmine states that it's caused by that test, but you're saying it might be wrong? When I remove the stopPropagation, it works (but the test fails obviously). I also console.log'd in the test, and I think it froze when clicking. I'm not using protractor. I'm not at work right now and can't check the code, but I'll look at it more on monday

Comment: I removed the tests and all the tests passed. None of the tests in the project have a `done` argument passed to the function, so they all run synchronously.